# azure creating database EF code first

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, azure

I have codefirst application that works nice on localhost, but has a problem with Azure database. the problem is that i cant dropCreateDatabaseAlways. it gives timeout error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding.'

I tried the folowing in dbcontext constructor:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DbSporter") {
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
}
```

but i was not able to increase the command timeout. it still gives error after about 30 sec.

I also tried to increase command timeout and connection timeout from web.config. didn't work.

i tried two different connections strings:

1) `connectionString="Data Source=tcp:sportit.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Sporter;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sporter;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=180;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"`

2) `connectionString="Data Source=tcp:sportit.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Sporter;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sporter;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=180;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"`

both of them have same result.
is there some trick or tip i should know about creating azure database with EF codefirst?

Comment: can you connect to the database using management studio? you often need add you ip from azure console.

Comment: Both the connection strings are **same**, and you can always get your connection string from your azure web app.

Comment: @LeiYang i can access my databas using VS built-in "SQL Server Object Explorer" and also using software "HeidiSQL"

Comment: @NiravMadariya i got the second connection string from azure web...

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the ADO.NET connectionString would look like as follows:

> Server=tcp:{your_sql_server_name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_database_name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

According to your description, I created my MVC website application and set the database initializer as `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` to test this issue. With the default timeout for connection and command, I could also encounter the timeout issue. Then, I tried to increase the timeout to 300 seconds, and I could drop and recreate the azure database. Here are the code snippet, you could refer to them:

**DbContext、Initializer、Model**

```
{
    public class BruceDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public BruceDBContext() : base("name=defaultConnectionString")
        {
            this.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }

    public class BruceInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BruceDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BruceDBContext context)
        {
            var companies = new List<Company>
            {
                new Company { Name = "AAA", City = "Eindhoven", Streetname="Street 12" },
                new Company { Name = "BBB", City = "Rotterdam", Streetname = "Street 12" },
                new Company { Name = "CCC", City = "Eindhoven", Streetname = "Street 12" },
                new Company { Name = "EEE", City = "Eindhoven", Streetname = "Street 12" }
            };

            companies.ForEach(s => context.Companies.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }

    [Table("Company")]
    public class Company
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Streetname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs > Application_Start**

```
Database.SetInitializer<BruceDBContext>(new BruceInitializer());
```

**Connection String**

```
<add name="defaultConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:brucesqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=brucetest4;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=brucechen;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**Result**

[image]